# Magento 2: 2 databases, only one with table_prefix

Tags: magento2, database, prefix

I have defined an additional custom database connection in `etc/env.php`:

```
'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => 'abc_',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'db1',
            'username' => 'db1',
            'password' => 'pw1',
            'active' => '1'
        ],
        'custom' => [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'dbname' => 'db2',
            'username' => 'db2',
            'password' => 'pw2',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
],
```

Tables inside the default connection all have the prefix `abc_`. The tables in the custom connection don't have a prefix. Unfortunately the `table_prefix` option seems to apply to all defined connections.

Is there a way to have this setting on a connection basis?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. It seems that there's no other solution to it aside from creating an around plugin on the getTableName

I would suggest you create an around plugin on Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection

Since the method getTableName, is the one responsible for adding in the table prefix.

Answer (score -1):

replace  `'table_prefix' => 'abc_' with 'table_prefix' => ''` in env.php

Comment: One database HAS prefixes the other does not. But magento assumes the prefix for any connection. When I remove it the other DB is not accessible.

Comment: in your script try to add prefix for your custom data base table using     $connection  = $this->_resource->getConnection();
    $tableName   = $connection->getTableName('tablename_without_prefix');

Comment: There is no way for me to change the current state. The magento DB has prefixes and the other does not. I cannot change that because it is beyond the scope of my project (customer decided). I am not using raw sql queries but resource models that obviously retrieve the prefix from the global setting.

Comment: can you please add your error here

Comment: "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db2.abc_lot' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `abc_lot` AS `main_table`
   INNER JOIN `abc_lotartikel` AS `a` ON main_table.LOT_ID = a.LOT_ID GROUP BY `a`.`LOT_ID`". That database does not have prefixes so it is looking for the table "abc_lot" but there is only a table named "lot".